# Change the values inside a select tag, when I click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with a select tag that have some options. I want that when I click in the button to change the value in the select tag, and in that way the tag will have the value I define by

```
document.getElementById('fruits').innerHTML="computer"
```

In this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggb38/) it does not function when I click the button.

Comment: You want add new options or replace the existing options?

Comment: question is not clear. Can you explain more?

Comment: I want to replace the existing options. So when I click the button only the option "computer" to be in the select tag

Comment: try: `document.getElementById('fruits').options['option_name'].value="Meat";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function fill(){
    document.getElementById('fruits').innerHTML="<option>Meat</option>";}

<select id="fruits">
    <option> Apple</option>
    <option> Orange</option>
</select>
```

If I am getting you right then make these change in your code.

Comment: Can I ask you for something else? If Meat is a variable and it contain a string foe example var meat="tryit", how can I write document.getElementById('fruits').innerHTML="<option>Meat</option>", in order to output the value of the variable?

Comment: document.getElementById('fruits').innerHTML="<option>"+Meat+"</option>"

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you, but is there any way for changing the position of select tag, when i click the button. So I want the select tag to be margin-left:20px.

Comment: thanks and sorry for disturbing but I found it.  I used document.getElementById('s1').style.marginLeft="20px";

Answer (score 0):

As i see [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) you can try:

HTML:

```
<select id="sel">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="change" onclick="fill()">
```

JS:

```
function fill() {
    $('#sel').empty();
    $("#sel").append(new Option("Computer"));

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ggb38/10/)

Or with vanilla js you can try:

```
function fill(){
    document.getElementById('sel').innerHTML="<option>Computer</option>";
}
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/ggb38/17/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#change').click(function() {
    document.getElementById('fruits').innerHTML="<option>Meat</option>";
});
```

modified HTML to

```
<select id="fruits"> 
    <option> Apple</option>
    <option> Orange</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="change" name="change" id="change">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 your html is wrong. use the code like:

 <select id="fruits">
        <option>Apple</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
  </select>

  <input type="button" value="change" onclick="fill();" />

 And change the fill function to:

  function fill() {
        document.getElementById('fruits').innerHTML = "<option>Meat</option>";
    }
```